# What check to use to see if a player notices an uncomfortable NPC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have just started a new campaign and all the players are gathering at an Inn. One of the players has sat in the corner and is clearly uncomfortable with his surroundings.

I have another player who has rolled a Spot check to see if he notices the other player looking uncomfortable.

I.e., he sees the guy in the corner; he's not hiding. But what to roll to see if they see an unhappy character?

My guess is a Wisdom check, rather than a spot check? Does it even need a check? The other character isn't actively trying to hide, but is trying to go unnoticed in a corner.

Comment: Are these two player-characters (PCs) or a PC and a nonplayer-character (NPC)? (That is, the title asks about an NPC yet the question seems to be about two PCs.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Sense Motive

The Sense Motive skill is the social skill used to determine what people are feeling, how to approach them, or what is going on in a situation.  It is analoguous to Spot in that you can roll it not just directly in response to a Hide (or in this case, Bluff) check, but also to glean information about an environment that can be of advantage to a character.